# What's wrong with this quicksort function?

Tags: php, sorting

```
function quick($a) {
    if (count($a) < 2) return $a;
    $l = [];
    $r = [];
    $pivot = $a[0];
    foreach ($a as $val) {
        if ($val > $pivot) {
            $r[] = $val;
        } else {
            $l[] = $val;
        }
    }
    return array_merge(quick($l), [$pivot], quick($r));
}

print_r(quick($a));
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sort.php on line 46
```

Line 46 is `$l[] = $val;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple. You're getting nearly infinite recursion.

The reason is that you're not excluding the pivot point from the sub-arrays. So `$l` will always contain it. And if `$pivot` is not the smallest value in the array, you'll infinitely recurse with an empty `$r` array, and copying `$a` into `$l`...

Instead, you need to adjust your if condition and look at the pivot key:

```
$pivot = $a[0];
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    if ($key === 0) {
        continue; // pivot
    } elseif ($val > $pivot) {
        $r[] = $val;
    } else {
        $l[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's it! I just did `$pivot = array_shift($a)` and works, thanks

Comment: That can do it as well... Either way works. You just have to prevent it from making it into either of the two sub-arrays...

Comment: @ircmaxell Just out of curiosity is there ever a case where something like this would out perform the native php array sorting functions?

Comment: @Orangepill: I won't say *never*, but the chances are exceedingly small. The internal functions use quicksort, but an in-place varient which uses constant memory. You could theoretically get better performance with a merge sort in php under certain situations (already sorted for example), but it would be so small that it wouldn't be worth it. Basically, just use `usort()` or `sort()` if you need this for actual use (and not just educational purposes)...